# How do I access a MongoDB connection outside of a view in Pyramid?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pyramid

I followed the Pyramid Cookbook instructions for [MongoDB and Pyramid](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/database/mongodb.html), but that seems to link a database query to `request.db` which I can only get from my views. **How can I open a connection which can be called from inside a class method?**

I'm trying to set up a real barebones serializer for the objects in my project. I have a number of class definitions in my `resources/` folder to handle my projects data. I would like to give each of these objects self-contained `.save()` and `.find()` methods (similar to `mongoengine`) which will convert the objects' data into a dictionary and save that dictionary to MongoDB using `pymongo`.

It's easy enough to open a connection to MongoDB using `pymongo`. All you have to do is use `MongoClient`. The problem is that I don't want to open a new connection each time I instantiate an object or call a class. I'd like a single connection to be made in the egg's `main()` function, which I can then access when I need it (just like `request.db` in views).

Obviously I'm brand new to Pyramid, so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a module that initializes and holds MongDB connection inside resources/ package.

E.g. resources/connection.py

```
import pymongo

db = None

def initialize(settings):
  global db
  db = MongoClient(settings['mongo_uri'])
```

Then in your app main function:

```
from myapp.resources import connection


def main(global_config, **settings):
  # ...
  connection.initialize(settings)
  # ...
  config.add_request_method(lambda request: connection.client, 'db', reify=True)
```

In any other module (not views), just import connection module:

```
from myapp.resources import connection

connection.db.posts
```

IMHO, this approach is more scalable and unit testable than approach described in the cookbook.

Comment: Do note that this method will probably break in unpredictable ways when threading comes into play, you'd want to use a threadlocal object.

The cookbook answer is much better, this would require you pass request down to your models, but in most cases that isn't an issue, and increases testability.

Comment: pymongo's MongoClient is thread-safe and acts as connection pool in reality. [Link](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo)